# Why does this code cause a ConcurrentModificationException in Java?

Tags: java

Why does this code cause a ConcurrentModificationException in Java?

```
public class MainMenuState {
    protected void init() {
        this.addElements(
             new GUIElement()
             .addMousePressed((e, element) -> {
                   this.elements.add(new GUIElement()
                   .addMouseEntered((e, element) -> //...)
             }
        )
   );
}
```

`addElements` is defined as:

```
void addElements(GameElement... elements){
    this.elements.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements));
}
```

I expect the code to create another `GUIElement` and add it to list `elements` when I click the enclosing `GUIElement`. Instead, when it is clicked, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.
I understand that `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when a list is modified while elements are being added to it, but `mouseEntered` isn't called until after `elements` has been modified.

So how is this error occurring?

The error text:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
at code.state.GameState.render(GameState.java:34)
at code.state.Handler.render(Handler.java:32)
at code.state.Handler.render(Handler.java:28)
at code.frame.GameEngine.render(GameEngine.java:94)
at code.frame.GameEngine.run(GameEngine.java:68)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're rendering something to screen in the `code.frame.GameEngine.render()` method. The problem is you're using a `LinkedList` which is not thread-safe. Thus, it's possible to add a new `GUIElement` to `elements` while `code.frame.GameEngine.render()` method is iterating over `elements` (this happens asynchronously). You need to use a thread-safe collection like:

```
List<GUIElement> elements = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<GUIElement>());
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's enough context here to pinpoint exactly the cause of your issue. But one solution would be simply to use:

```
 List<Object> objList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

to instantiate the problematic list to simple synchronize access to it.